# Remove cherry-picked commits

Tags: git, github

Often I have to wait for the code review of PRs containing the code that I need in the new branch. I was wondering would it be possible to:

- create new branch
- add commits from pending PRs by `git cherry-pick`
- add other commits
- wait for PR to be merged
- remove the commits added by `git cherry-pick` (by `git rebase -i`)
- rebase the current branch by the "main" branch
- create a new PR

Thanks a lot.

Dragan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be perfectly possible. That said...

You can join the first two steps by just branching off of your  waiting branch `branch1` instead of `master`, then there is no need for cherry picking.

You can skip the interactive rebase as well - the common `git rebase master` will automatically detect that the changes from the original PR branch are already there and it will simply work as expected with minimal fuss. You can tell it to skip the commits from branch1 with the `--onto` option.

In summary:

```
git checkout branch1
git checkout -b branch2
... git commit, etc. ...
... wait for acceptance of PR of branch1, pull new master  ...
git checkout branch2
git rebase --onto master branch1 branch2
```

The interpretation of `--onto` is quite literal  "cherry pick all commits between branch1 and branch2 onto master". Those commits being exactly those that you added while waiting for the PR.